# Trying to set Row Visibility on a SSRS report based on if any rows have a specific value

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to set Row Visibility on a SSRS report. I have this expression but it generates error - not valid. 
How Can I turn on or off a row based on if rows exists where Fields!Transportation = "Train"?

```
=IIf((CountRows(Fields!Transportation.Value="Train"))>0,False,True)
```

Comment: Try adding a Scope parameter for your DataTable to your CountRows function..

Comment: If this expression is at a detail level, then you don't need to count.. just use                               =IIF(Fields!Transportation.Value="Train",False,True)